# Accessing element attributes of "Object #<HTMLDivElement>"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't figure this out - I'm trying to retrieve an attribute of my active slide in RoyalSlider. I managed to get the active slide's HTML content in what is an HTMLDivElement Object. In Chrome's console it shows as a tree view of the HTML element I want and its children. I want to access either the `id` of the element or my own custom attribute, but the error I keep getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'attr'
```

This is the line that outputs it:

```
console.log(jQuery('.royalSlider').data('royalSlider').currSlide.content.first()[0].attr("id"));
```

I know I need to use `jQuery('.royalSlider').data('royalSlider').currSlide.content` but I don't know about the rest. How can I access my custom attribute `slideId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement:

```
console.log(jQuery('.royalSlider').data('royalSlider').currSlide.content.first()[0].attr("id"));
```

The `[0]` gives you access to the HTML DOM object (using the jquery [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method), not the jquery version of it.  Get rid of the `[0]` and you should be able to call `attr`.

So the following should work:

```
console.log(jQuery('.royalSlider').data('royalSlider').currSlide.content.first().attr("id"));
```

Comment: Ahhhh! I tried every other combination, can't believe that one slipped through - thanks!